# Django - Extend the login function to save the last but one login datetime

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-authentication

I need to store additional information about the user: data of the last but one user login.
My idea is to perform an update on the login function to store properly this information.
As I am using the generic django login function I would like to perform it without changing much of what is working now.

My Custom user model:

```
class ExtendedUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    lbo_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
```

My urls.py (calls the built-in login function)

```
url(r'^accounts/login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
```

And my idea:

```
# login function
# ...
# Before storing the information of the current login, 
# Something like:
user.extendeduser.lbo_login = user.last_login
user.extendeduser.save()
# continue with the login function and update the last login field
```

Can you help me with that? How can I complement the built-in function?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are login and logout signals sent by Django that You can use for this purpose: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly what I needed. As the signal is called once the registration has been done and the user last_login has been updated, I created a new field in my custom user model. My signal looks like this: `user.extendeduser.lbo_login = user.extendeduser.act_login
    user.extendeduser.act_login = user.last_login`